# Why application is crashing during calling next activity in Android?

Tags: android

Can any one suggest me, Why my application is crashing when calling next activity? I am having default frame animation in both activity which is running inside `onWindowFocuschanged()` method..is there any solution to run it smoothly.

Comment: put some code hor you r going from one activity to another.

Comment: Please add some log or code which you are trying this could make us understand your problem!

Comment: Ok,I am sorry,I will take care of this in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you decleared your activity in manifest file then add it then use below code snippet

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,NextActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```